# REST- SOAP - oData - Web API explanation

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I've been a developer since 1 year ago working mostly with C#, Javascript and Microsoft Dynamics CRM. However, there's a topic that, to be honest, I do not undertand at all, this is Web Services.

I know that they are used to "connect" two systems and transfer information using XML. The thing is that I do not understand the differences between SOAP, REST, oDATA and other terminoligies related to this.

So, I was wondering... is there any easy explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST is based on HTTP so it's good for web services. OData is a standardized REST protocol so you don't need to invent your own api. SOAP does not use HTTP so is used for integration within a businesses network.